# ts Cannot find the module

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, nodejs, npm

I am very new to the SPFx I just started. I was making my first web part in Visual Studio Code but I was having some difficulty in my code. May be somebody can help. I have scss module in the same folder **FeedbackWebPart.module.scss**

[image]

But in my FeedbackWebPart.ts show me error **[ts] Cannot find the module './FeedbackWebPart.module.scss'**
[image]

Can somebody tell me what is wrong as this code is not written by me but it generated by `Yomean @microsoft/sharepoint`

Forgot to mention version of the all tool chain I used
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is bug in visual studio code or may be in yomean or may be in typescript because when I run

> `gulp serve`

it compile web part and resolve the issue by it self. Hope this can help someone else.

Comment: If you look at the files in the folder, you'll see a `.module.scss.ts` and a `module.scss` file, im guessing the ts is not compiled before the first build or somehting

Answer (score 0):

Its just an Code Editor issues. The build will be successful.

Answer (score 0):

It's the editor issue. 
Just close and open the editor, the error will be gone.
Or just ignore it, `gulp serve` will run fine.